# For mains attached circuits: what do I need to protect against and how do I do it?

Tags: mains, circuit-protection

I don't have a lot of experience with mains voltage and designing protection circuits for them.  I'm not sure:

A) What do I need to protect against?  I know I don't need to worry about 10kV voltage transients on the mains line, but what about 300V spikes?  Mains voltage is 120Vrms nominal (in the US, for residential users), but what is the maximum that should be expected and planned for.

B) How do I protect against it?  For voltage transients I can use a TVS diode, or a MOV, but I don't know how to select one.  When do I use one over the other?  For overvoltage protection, is there an AC version of a crowbar?

What are good guidelines about what to protect against, and how to do it for mains circuits?

Note:

To try and head off the inevitable "close for too vague" votes, I want to mention that I'm only interested in:

- "what are the common voltage issues that residential mains wiring will present to a circuit on it" and
- "what are the *basics* of protecting against these issues"

I realize that there are probably many books written about circuit protection circuits, but I think that a very basic answer would be very appropriate here.

Comment: Your question will probably be closed as being too broad. You need to ask a specific question. Start with defining what you want to protect. Light bulbs or medical life-support systems?

Comment: @Transistor: The relevant part of the "how to ask questions" page is about vagueness, not broadness.  This isn't vague is it?  If we close everything that is "too broad" this site is going to become uselessly filled with questions that don't have any meaning beyond their specific intent.

Comment: @op I partially agree with you. A too broad question cannot be answered, while something too specific is less reusable. Procedure on this board is to close too broad questions anyway, and we can't change that, and your question is quite broad indeed. You could write a book about it broad. Try to be more specific while also leaving room to generic and useful answers.

Comment: Are you interested in protecting your equipment from abnormal behavior of the line, or are you interested in protecting your users from getting electrocuted?

Comment: @VladimirCravero: I'm looking for the simple "I want to plug in a circuit to my mains voltage, what do I need to watch out for, and how do I watch out for it" answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Just the equipment.  And I'm looking for the "normal abnormal".  I know that AC mains voltage frequently has voltage transients on it (someone plugs in a motor in the other room or something similar), but I don't know how big they are.  I also know they should be protected from, but I'm not sure what kind of circuit I should use to protect from them.

Comment: @AndrewSpott -- are you concerned solely with the safety of your *circuitry*, or do you have questions about keeping the circuit from doing untoward things to you?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: at the moment, I'm concerned solely with the safety of the circuit.  If I have a circuit, and I want to attach it to mains voltage and leave it for a year, I want to have a good probability of coming back to a still standing house and a still working circuit, or a circuit that has a blown fuse, but is otherwise ok.

Comment: @AndrewSpott -- alright then -- I think the existing answers are good then.

Comment: Murphy dictates that someone *will* manage to plug your device into a 230V socket, especially if it's something that people might take on a trip to Europe. At the very least, this should fail safely.

Comment: @msalters:  unlikely: the device is a one off for me, and it will also work fine on 230V.  It is mostly a pass through.

Comment: Consider what happens if lightning hits a power line somewhere on the path from the power station to your house.  About all you can do about that is supply a path for part of the lightning current to reach ground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your wattmeter only has arc suppression gap set at 6kV standard. So you can expect anything less than that and possibly more , likely in Florida , with transients that do not ionize the gap.

This is why burnt out LEDs in Florida are so common with cheap PAR Lamps.

One way to suppress peak voltage is via  line filter using two X1 caps and a choke or a 3rd order LPF.  This reduces the 10kV spikes to <3kV or even as low as 300V but stretches them out in time.

So Optoisolator products assume you know about this and are all rated for 3kV isolation.

Any protection you add to clamp these voltages must be able to,handle the current that follows.

Gas tubes can handle 10kA surges but expect you to fuse the input.

MOV's are cheap and good but can only absorb occasional surges and will fail after so many accumulative Joules in energy. Chokes allow the rise rate in current to be limited until they saturate , then they behave like wirewound resistors.

Here is some industrial design [background](http://www.industrial-electronics.com/switching-power-supply_1-2.html) for line filters.  Line filters in LED bulbs must pass these tests, and not all,suppliers are legit in saying they are compliant.

> There is no "one solution fits all" because of other requirements for low cost, high reliability, and new EMC compliance rules for devices >= 100W must have power factor >=0.9 using active PFC etc.

Comment: Thanks!  What is the frequency of surges on the line (is there a national average)?  How much energy is in a typical surge?  If I use a MOV, do I need to spec it against 1 surge a day, 1 surge a week, a year?  Is there a reason you didn't talk about TVS diodes?

Comment: I see that the link you provided mentioned that, thanks.

Comment: @AndrewSpott, why you are so quick to mark answers as answers?

Comment: @Ali Chen: because he answered all my questions.  I was a little quick for this one, but I'm not yearning for more information.

Comment: Ali < if it's any consolation I'll vote for your link, which describes all the test PLT and ELF standards that I used to write for a Corporate environment decades before.

Answer (score 10):

Protection of electronic equipment is normally defined in IEC 61000 standard. It includes protection against ESD (61000-4-2), immunity to EFT (61000-4-4), 61000-4-5 (lightening surge immunity), etc. The standard is a collective wisdom of what kind of surges are typically there, and defines several classes of equipment protection. Here is an [example from Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva711/slva711.pdf), with examples of what to protect against, and partially how. There are many other good write-ups, with examples of protection solutions. The keyword is "IEC 61000".